# Referring to another cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi how do I make the bold value ("ES") equal a value within cell b2 in another sheet called "YYY" in the same workbook as 'overview data' ?

```vb
Sub Macro3()

' Macro3 Macro

    With Sheets("overview data").Range("a1:ca5000")
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=**"ES"**
        .AutoFilter Field:=43, Criteria1:="<12"
        .AutoFilter Field:=78, Criteria1:=Array("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `=worksheets("YYY").range("b2").value`?

Comment: Can you create a macro that records your actions in excel? If so, after this action you can extract the code for your target.

Comment: Thanks @SJR works perfect